# Flutter Firebase dynamic links on IOS not working: [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm trying to use dynamic links in my flutter app to invite new users.
It works fine on Android but, It does not workin on IOS.
the message is:

```
2021-08-30 15:31:09.260470+0900 Runner[9221:902508] 8.3.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][IACS023001] Deep Link does not contain valid required params. URL params: {  
    "_cpb" = 1;  
    "_cpt" = cpit;  
    "_fpb" = "CJsFEPcCGgVrby1rcg==";  
    "_iumchkactval" = 1;  
    "_iumenbl" = 1;  
    "_osl" = "https://myapp.page.link/ryZWzXFzVqY3sjE4A";  
    "_plt" = 981;  
    "_uit" = 2105;  
    apn = "com.example.myapp";  
    cid = 2464839987823306368;  
    ibi = "com.example.myappios";  
    isi = app store id;  
    link = "https://invite.friends.myapp/invite_from?uid={uid_string}";  
}
```

My codes:

Generating dynamic links

```
String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
                  final DynamicLinkParameters parameters =
                      DynamicLinkParameters(
                    uriPrefix: 'https://potendogs.page.link',
                    link: Uri.parse(
                        'https://invite.friends.myapp/invite_from?uid=$uid'),
                    androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
                      packageName: 'com.example.myapp',
                    ),
                    iosParameters: IosParameters(
                      bundleId: 'com.example.myappios',
                      appStoreId: 'app store id',
                    ),
                  );
                  final ShortDynamicLink shortUrl =
                      await parameters.buildShortLink();
                  Share.share('invite_message'.tr() + shortUrl.shortUrl.toString());
```

Receiving dynamic links

```
void initDynamicLinks() async {
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
        onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData? dynamicLink) async {
      final Uri? deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;

      if (deepLink != null) {
        String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
        String? ownerUid = deepLink.queryParameters['uid'];
        if (uid != null && ownerUid != null) {
          _inviteCouponBloc
              .add(NewUserInviteCouponEvent(uid: uid, ownerUid: ownerUid));
        }
      }
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('OnLinkError');
      print(e.message);
      print(e.stacktrace);
    });

    final PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri? deepLink = data?.link;

    if (deepLink != null) {
      if (widget.isNewUser) {
        String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
        String? ownerUid = deepLink.queryParameters['uid'];
        if (uid != null && ownerUid != null) {
          _inviteCouponBloc
              .add(NewUserInviteCouponEvent(uid: uid, ownerUid: ownerUid));
        } else {
          print('firebase uid is null');
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I call `initDynamicLinks()` in `initState()`

The Generated dynamic link(short) look like this: https://myapp.page.link/Df6MA2Xf34CTENgs9
But in IOS, some log shows how IOS get dynamic links link this

```
"iOS handleLink: https://myapp.page.link/?link=https://invite.friends.myapp/invite_from?uid%3D66kWqpCU1ddHfErvtyucOHK3KoI3&apn=com.example.myapp&isi={app store id}&ibi=com.example.myappios&cid=2464839987823306368&_osl=https://myapp.page.link/ryZWzXFzVqY3sjE4A&_fpb=CJsFEPcCGgVrby1rcg==&_cpt=cpit&_iumenbl=1&_iumchkactval=1&_plt=981&_uit=2105&_cpb=1"
```

how can I solve this problem?

***note***
I have different ios and android bundle id.
android bundle id: com.example.myapp
ios bundle id: com.example.myappios

I filled every inputs on firebase console.

additionally, There's warning when i generate dynamic links like:
[Android app 'com.example.myappios' lacks SHA256. AppLinks is not enabled for the app. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#android-sha256-absent],

iOS app 'com.example.myapp' lacks App ID Prefix. UniversalLinks is not enabled for the app. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/debug#ios-team-id-absent],

There is no configuration to prevent phishing on this domain https://myapp.page.link. Setup URL patterns to whitelist in the Firebase Dynamic Links console. [https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9021429]]

### edit

The variable `deepLink` from `dynamicLink?.link` and
`await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink()?.link` is null

Answer (score 0):

Check if an external API or service are modifying your url.

In my case a payment api modify the url and iOS devices crashed.